# How to make unicorn.rb print to stdout during bootup?=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn

I have a unicorn config at config/unicorn.rb and have a bunch of puts statements in it. The puts appear in the stdout file when unicorn boots fine. They don't appear when unciron boot fails due to an unavailable backend. Is there way to get puts working during unicorn boot?